# Customizing mat paginator

Tags: angular, pagination

I am trying to build a list page which has large number of data items so I used mat-paginator for simplicity in reading. I tried to customize styles in mat-paginator but I couldn't do much. Right now my paginator looks like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6Sbd.png)
I want to make it look like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pbkg.png)

My current CSS code for paginator is:

```
.mat-paginator-page-size{
      display: none !important;
}
.mat-paginator-range-label{
      display: none !important;
}

.mat-icon-button{
      border-radius: none;
      background-color: #00a6ff;
      height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can give by using this class

> .mat-icon-button {
> border: solid blue !important;
> border-radius: 5px !important;
> }

and put this in the main CSS file in the case of Angular Style.css is the main CSS file.

Comment: Thank you this works. But how can i show the list of clickable page numbers like the one in the image.

Comment: @GaneshGoel can you please explain the question I did not get you.

Comment: Can you please explain how can i add the page numbers in paginator tab like if there are 10pages, then it will display each page number 1 to 10 between the previous and next buttons like the ones in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pbkg.png. Also when i click on the page number it will directly take me to that page.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to customize the `mat-paginator` within the component HTML file.

Take a look at the following example;

```
  <mat-paginator #paginator
    [length]=result.count
    [pageSize]=result.pageSize
    [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20, 50, 100]"
    [pageIndex]=result.page
    (page)="getNextPage($event)"
    [showFirstLastButtons]="true">
  </mat-paginator>
```

We can provide page size chunks, show specific pagination buttons and so on.

You can read more about its API documentation via this link https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api

There's also configurable pagination example on Stackblitz here that you can experiment with
https://stackblitz.com/angular/ngdejmepgbr?file=app/paginator-configurable-example.html

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own components inside a mat-paginator

you can inspire by this code

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  // get element
  const list = this.customPagingItems.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName("mat-paginator-range-actions");
  if (!!list[0]) {
    // add what you need
    const div = this.renderer.createElement("div");
    this.renderer.addClass(div, "mat-paginator-page-info");
    list[0].appendChild(div);
 }
}
```

...

```
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    // update added elements if needed
    const list = this.customPagingItems.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName("mat-paginator-page-info");
    if (!!list[0]) list[0].innerHTML = `Page ${this.currentPage.toString()} of ${this.totalPages.toString()}`;
  }
```

You can rearrange its order by using `order: N` in css